# entity_type_code_entity table is empty in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7, eav, eav-attributes

I am trying to insert data into the EAV tables, but my main entity table isn't saving any data but the value tables data is inserted.
My Entity Type code is `vinay_employee`, my table `vinay_employee_entity` has three columns `entity_id` `employee_name` and `employee_email`. Data is not inserting into `vinay_employee_entity` when i am calling `save()` function but other values tables like `vinay_employee_entity_datetime` get their data.

**Model/EmployeeData.php**

```
namespace Vinay\Employee\Model;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Vinay\Employee\Api\Data\EmployeeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;

class EmployeeData extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{

    const ENTITY = "vinay_employee";

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Vinay\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\EmployeeData');
    }
}
```

**ResourceModel/EmployeeData.php**

```
namespace Vinay\Employee\Model\ResourceModel;

class EmployeeData extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity{
    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_read = 'vinay_employee_read';
        $this->_write = 'vinay_employee_write';
    }
    
    public function getEntityType() {
        if(empty($this->_type)) {
            $this->setType(\Vinay\Employee\Model\EmployeeData::ENTITY);
        }

        return parent::getEntityType();
    } 
}
```

**Controller/Adminhtml/Emp/Save.php**

```
namespace Vinay\Employee\Controller\Adminhtml\Emp;

class Save extends \Vinay\Employee\Controller\Adminhtml\Emp\AbstractAction {

    //put your code here

    private $connection;
    private $employeeDataFactory;
    private $employee, $employeeDataFactoryResource, $registry;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
            \Vinay\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\EmployeeDataFactory $employeeDataFactoryResource,
            \Vinay\Employee\Model\EmployeeDataFactory $employeeDataFactory) {
        $this->connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->employee = $employeeDataFactory;
        $this->registry= $registry;
        $this->employeeDataFactoryResource = $employeeDataFactoryResource;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $postObj = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        echo "<pre>";
        $employeeModel = $this->employee->create(["employee_name", "employee_email"]);
        $result = $employeeModel->setData($postObj)->save();
        print_r($result->getData());
        die();
        $this->employeeDataFactoryResource->create()->save($employeeModel);
        return $this->_redirect("employee/emp/index");
    }
}
```

**$result**

```
Array
(
    [form_key] => HSR4TCVPyzs6r6Wi
    [employee_name] => vinn
    [employee_email] => viin
    [employee_address] => ddsdds
    [is_permanent] => 0
    [joined_at] => 2021-04-15 10:02:35
    [vinaykharayat11] => ssdsd
    [parent_id] => 0
    [created_at] => 2021-04-15 04:32:37
    [updated_at] => 2021-04-15 04:32:37
    [entity_id] => 37
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my main entity table i.e `vinay_employee_entity` attributes i.e. `employee_name` `employee_email` should also be in `eav_attribute` table.